# Angular service is not triggered the back end when call is made from external client machine

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Front end is developed in Angular 6 and back-end is springboot rest controller.
Locally as well as in same network, both the services are working fine. when i tried to access the angular service from external internet. Angular GUI is opened like Login and register page but when tried to login or register, In this case angular service communicate with back-end springboot application over http requests. I tried to take the wireshark trace but it seems no http request trigger from my angular service while if i execute the same login request within same network (client and server machine) then request works and Wireshark also captured all the http request and response.

In case of external network, angular service is not trigger the http request towards the backend application.

any help will be appropriated.

-Randhir

Comment: IF it's a GET call, make sure to subscribe to it. It's a cold observable and the call won't be made until it is subscribed to.

Comment: Seems a cross domain issue. Are your services on same domain as the server distributing front ?

Comment: Yes, it seems more cross domain issue. Front end angular application is running on machine IP:4200 and back end spring boot application running on machine IP:8080. Both applications are running on same machine. 
Currently working scenario: machine 1 on which both applications are deployed and machine 2 from where i am accessing the front-end application connected in same network (local network, connected to same modem). In this case both applications connectivity working fine.
Not working case: If machine 1 is connected to my modem and machine 2 connected to another internet connection.